# Count ways to form an $n$ digit number such that adjacent digits are co-primes?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Eg.
$X = 3$ (allowed digits $1-3$  and digit limit ($1-9$)) 
$N = 2$

$(12), (13), (11), (23), (21), (32), (31)$

ans $= 7$

I tried to calculate the answer but the complexity to find the answer is O(n)

like in this case
count of co-primes for 1 is 3 (1,2,3), 2 is 2 (1,3), 3 is 2 (1,2)

ans(n) denotes answer for n digit number

dp(i,n) denotes answer for n digit number ending with i.

ans(2) = dp(1,2)+ dp(2,2) + dp(3,2)

dp(1,1)=1, dp(2,1) =1, dp(3,1)=1  (base case since there is only 1 way to form 1 digit number ending with a particular number)

dp(1,2) = dp(1,1)+dp(2,1)+dp(3,1) ( sum of all co-prime digit dp(i,n-1) )

dp(2,2) = dp(1,1)+dp(3,1)

dp(3,2) = dp(1,1)+dp(2,1)

ans(2) = 3 + 2 + 2

ans = 7

can we do this with a better time complexity?

Comment: Please explain your question more clearly.  Why can we not add $(22)$ at the end?  and $(33)$ at the beginning?  what is the digit limit $1-9$ about?  It looks like $N$ is the number of digits but you don't say that.

Comment: As stated in question ,since 2 and 2 are not co-primes we don't include it in the count. Digit limit is basically allowed digits to form the number (in this case 1,2 and 3) and N is the length of the number.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: That was why I asked for a clearer question. I thought the two digit numbers were supposed to be Corrine, not the digits of each number

Comment: Is it clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can find a closed form by using the techniques of [linear recurrence relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_homogeneous_linear_recurrence_relations_with_constant_coefficients).  You have a set of coupled recurrence relations, which you can write as
$$dp(i,n)=\begin {pmatrix}1&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}dp(i,n-1)$$
where $dp(i,n)$ is a column vector with $i$ being the last digit and $n$ the number of digits.  You start with $dp(i,1)=\begin {pmatrix}1\\1\\1\end {pmatrix}$ because you can use any digit in the first position.  You can diagonalize the matrix and find its [eigenvalues and eigenvectors](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigenvalues%20and%20eigenvectors&assumption=%7B%22F%22,%20%22Eigenvector%22,%20%22eigvecmatrix%22%7D%20-%3E%22%7B%7B1,1,1%7D,%7B1,0,1%7D,%7B1,1,0%7D%7D%22).  The dominant eigenvalue is $1+\sqrt 2$, so the total number of numbers increases by about that factor each time.  The other two eigenvalues are $-1, 1-\sqrt 2$, so $ans(n)=a(1+\sqrt 2)^n+b(-1)^n+c(1-\sqrt 2)^n$ where you can find $a,b,c$ from the first three values

Comment: Thanks a lot. Figured out we can solve linear recurrence using matrix exponentiation also.